# search & replace a list of dictionaries by another list of dictionaries and a given attribute

Tags: ansible, jinja2

is it possible to search and replace the following (source) list of dictionaries:

```
- k: aaa
  v: 1
- k: bbb
  v: 2
- k: bbb
  v: 3
  v2: should be kept from source
- k: bbb
- k: ccc
  v: 4
```

by this (search & replace) list of dictionaries, using 'k' as index:

```
- k: bbb     # search for index k:bbb in the source and replace/add key-value v:99 
  v: 99
- k: ccc     # search for index k:ccc in the source and replace/add key-values v:88 and v2:77 
  v: 88
  v2: 77
- k: xxxxx   # search for index k:xxxxx in the source. as not found, just skip
  v: 66
```

to produce

```
- k: aaa   # index not found: keep everything as it is in the source
  v: 1
- k: bbb   # index found: replace value of v
  v: 99
- k: bbb   # index found: replace value of v, keep v2 from source
  v: 99
  v2: should be kept from source
- k: bbb   # index found: add missing key-value v:99
  v: 99
- k: ccc   # index found: replace value of v, add key-value v2:77
  v: 88
  v2: 77
```

it is similar to `community.general.lists_mergeby`, but not the same.

hope, this is possible with some existing filters.

Comment: so much complexity, why is this required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the lists

```yaml
    l1:
      - {k: aaa, v: 1}
      - {k: bbb, v: 2}
      - {k: bbb, v: 3, v2: should be kept from source}
      - {k: bbb}
      - {k: ccc, v: 4}
    l2:
      - {k: bbb, v: 99}
      - {k: ccc, v: 88, v2: 77}
      - {k: xxxxx, v: 66}
```

Convert the second list to a dictionary

```yaml
  d2: "{{ dict(l2|map(attribute='k')|
               zip(l2|ansible.utils.remove_keys(target=['k']))) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  d2:
    bbb: {v: 99}
    ccc: {v: 88, v2: 77}
    xxxxx: {v: 66}
```

---

Notes:

- It is not necessary to remove the key *k*. The resulting list *l3* will be the same.

  ```yaml
  d2: "{{ dict(l2|map(attribute='k')|zip(l2)) }}"
  ```
- Optionally, use *json_query*

  ```yaml
  d2: "{{ dict(l2|json_query('[].[k, @]')) }}"
  ```

  gives the same result

  ```yaml
  d2:
    bbb: {k: bbb, v: 99}
    ccc: {k: ccc, v: 88, v2: 77}
    xxxxx: {k: xxxxx, v: 66}
  ```

---

Iterate the first list and combine items

```yaml
  l3: |
    [{% for i in l1 %}
    {{ i|combine(d2[i.k]|d({})) }},
    {% endfor %}]
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  l3:
    - {k: aaa, v: 1}
    - {k: bbb, v: 99}
    - {k: bbb, v: 99, v2: should be kept from source}
    - {k: bbb, v: 99}
    - {k: ccc, v: 88, v2: 77}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    l1:
      - {k: aaa, v: 1}
      - {k: bbb, v: 2}
      - {k: bbb, v: 3, v2: should be kept from source}
      - {k: bbb}
      - {k: ccc, v: 4}
    l2:
      - {k: bbb, v: 99}
      - {k: ccc, v: 88, v2: 77}
      - {k: xxxxx, v: 66}

    d2: "{{ dict(l2|map(attribute='k')|zip(l2)) }}"
    l3: |
      [{% for i in l1 %}
      {{ i|combine(d2[i.k]|d({})) }},
      {% endfor %}]

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: d2|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: l3|to_yaml
```